# Using TransactionScope with Parallel.Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, transactions, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am trying to use Transaction with Parallel.Foreach

Code Snippet :

```
List<int> iList = new List<int>(); // Having int random numbers

/// To check final collection count

ConcurrentQueue<int> q= new ConcurrentQueue<in>();

using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
{

    Transaction rootTr = Transaction.Current;

    Parallel.ForEach(iLIst, item =>
    {

        DependentTransaction dt = rootTr.DependentClone(DependentCloneOption.RollbackIfNotComplete);

        if(item == 7)
             throw new ArgumentException("7 occurred"); // This is throwing Exception

        q.Enqueue(item);

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        dt.Complete();
    });

    ts.Complete();
}
```

But I am getting exception but I see value in queue(q).

I want completely rollback all the parallel processing item so that queue(q) is empty in case of failure.

Comment: Using TPL compute calls with transactions is probably a bad idea and defeats the purpose of parallelism when waiting for I/O to complete.   So is **Thread.Sleep(5000);**.  You probably should use _TPL DataFlow_

Comment: May be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053682/adding-transaction-scope-to-parallel-foreach

Comment: `ConcurrentQueue` is not transaction-aware, period. Is `q.Enqueue` a stand-in for something that uses external resources or is it the actual thing you want to happen transactionally? The simplest way to get an empty queue when failure happens is to empty the queue in a `catch`.

Comment: Thread.Sleep(5000);  denotes some work done. ConcurrentQueue<int> q==> denotes if transaction is not successful it should rollback any changes done to queue and it should be empty. Think Queue of some shared resource whose output is from parallel processing (i.e. Parallel.Foreach)

Comment: It's pointless to think of "some" shared resource. In order to do anything with `TransactionScope`, you need transaction-aware classes (like `SqlConnection`). You cannot solve generic transaction-like problems using `TransactionScope` (unless you wrote the infrastructure for it). Why not add the item to the queue only at the end of a `try` block, ensuring that it's never added in the first place if it runs into an exception? Rollback semantics needlessly complicate things, because they require actual *support* for rolling things back.

Comment: A queue inherently *cannot* have transaction semantics except for all-or-nothing, because otherwise it would be necessary to remove an item from somewhere other than the beginning of the queue, which isn't a queue operation. And if all you want *is* all-or-nothing, set a shared variable `failure` to `true` and empty the queue after the `ForEach`.